# Implementing a bias in coin toss simulation

Tags: python, numpy, random, coin-flipping

I want to simulate a biased coin being flipped 2048 times and record the results from each attempt, along with the total count of each coin. My current code is fully functional and is able to simulate a fair coin, but I'm unsure about how to implement a bias of 0.25 within my current code. What can I do to add this particular bias?

```py
def heads_tails(number_of_flips):
    tails_count = 0
    heads_count = 0
    for i in range(number_of_flips):
        rand = random.randint(1,2)
        if rand == 1:
            tails_count += 1
            print(tails_count, 'tails')
        else:
            heads_count += 1
            print(heads_count, 'heads')
    print('Total Heads: ', heads_count)
    print('Total Tails: ', tails_count)

heads_tails(2048)
```

Comment: note that this is just the binomial distribution: `heads_count = numpy.random.binomial(number_of_flips, 0.25)`.  this efficiently flips lots of coins and just gives you the count back, with probability of getting heads being 1/4.  this scales as O(1) while your code is O(n) in the number of coin flips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify this part of your code

```
rand = random.randint(1,2)
    if rand == 1:
```

to

```
rand = random.random() # randoms a value between 0.0 and 1.0
    if rand < 0.25:
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), with the required weights.

```py
rand = random.choices((1,2),weights=(0.4,0.6))  # 40% for 1 , and 60% for 2
```